# How can I solve this problem of installation xampp on fedora?

Tags: apache, installation, xampp, fedora

**When I run xampp on fedora this error is showing up on application log**

Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

can anyone tell me how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: in fedora `sudo dnf install libnsl` works like a charm

Answer (score 25):

it seems you're missing libnsl. install it through this command:

```
sudo dnf install libnsl
```

In case this doesn't work you can then download it manually:

1. Visit https://pkgs.org/
2. In the search box (pkgs.org of course) type libnsl.so.1 and choose the appropriate OS. The version shown might be higher e.g libnsl-2.28-9.fc29.x86_64.rpm, but it doesn't matter, the file needed is also included in this very package.
3. In the terminal, navigate to the directory where the .rpm was downloaded.
4. Type the following command to install it:

   ```
   sudo rpm libnsl-2.XX-X.fc29.x86_64.rpm
   ```

Upon completion everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search returns this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/8hlhlv/xampp_with_fedora_28/

The suggested fix is installing libnsl from this source:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libnsl.so.1%28%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search+...&system=fedora&arch=

Comment: that shows up to me

Starting Apache Web Server...
/opt/lampp/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/opt/lampp/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started